# Error SignalR connect to Network Load Balancing(NLB ) net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_INTERFERENCE?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, push-notification

I have a simple SingulaR connect to Network Load Balancing(NLB) example that I've added to a legacy ASP.Net MVC application but have error like this

[image: Error SignalR with NLB]

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://mytest.com/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=4.1&connectionToken=DFGDFSGDFSGDSFGDFSGDFGFjnmH8Oj7%2F76WUwFvgnoaQlN%2FuttLoF9hSMerB4pf%2B0x69XOu5G8R3qtz20Gpm8NdBYijl621dEkfeoRheiOjC4%2FM6OeRX343uixpdPcK%2Bt1&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22cls_hub%22%7D%5D&tid=20' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_INTERFERENCE